# error on ggplot2: mapping` must be created by `aes()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, modeling, beta

This are my codes and the error i got below. Thank you

```
beta_top %>%
  mutate(term = reorder_within(term, beta, topic)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(beta, term, fill = factor(topic))) +
  geom_col(show, legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(-topic, scales = "free") +
  scale_y_reordered()
```

> Error in `geom_col()`:
> ! `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I try to plot a chart for the k=4 topics model for beta that i want to display using ggplot.

Comment: The problem is that your first argument to `geom_col` is `show`. You haven't told us what this is, but I'm pretty sure if you take it out you won't get the error.

Comment: Just a guess but perhaps you want `show.legend = FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you, I used the show.legend, and it worked. Many thanks